# How to do GPU programming on Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, gpu

I want to try GPU programming. The GPU of my MacBook Air is Intel HD Graphics 3000, so I think I cannot use CUDA.

I did some research and ran into OpenCL. But in the homepage, it is said that

> OpenCL™ (Open Computing Language) is a low-level API for heterogeneous
>   computing that runs on CUDA-powered GPUs.

I think my GPU is not CUDA-powered, so maybe OpenCL cannot be used either.

Then I wonder how can I do GPU programming on my MacBook Air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By GPU Programming I am assuming you mean high performance parallel calculations on the GPU without graphics (since you mention OpenCL and CUDA).

If so this link may be helpful: https://anteru.net/2012/11/03/2009/.

And that card definitely can't use CUDA.

Comment: I mean 'high performance parallel calculations', thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA supported by NVIDIA only because it is NVIDIA invention. OpenCL is open standard made as an answer of AMD on NVIDIAs CUDA. OpenCL supported widely by various platforms including Nvidia, Intel and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/opencl/).